# Select row which matched to the words from another dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a bit confused about the keyword to search this problem. Could you help me or give me any suggestion to solve this problem in R

I have the dataframe A like this

```
list_fruit
<chr>
Orange
Grape
Watermelon
Mango
```

and I want to bring this dataframe match with another dataset B

This is dataset B

```
Fruit      Number    Price
<chr>      <int>     <int>
Banana      56        25
Watermelon  5         100
Pineapple   96        150
Guava       47        20
Orange      3         120
```

so the rows of 'Watermelon' and 'Orange' will be selected
and were collected in new dataframe

```
Fruit      Number    Price
<chr>      <int>     <int>
Watermelon  5         100
Orange      3         120
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `inner_join`. Let's call your first data frame df1 and the second df2. Then:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = c("list_fruit" = "Fruit"))
#>   list_fruit Number Price
#> 1     Orange      3   120
#> 2 Watermelon      5   100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

From the help page:

> inner_join(): includes all rows in x and y.

Here, this means you match the columns by `list_fruit` in df1 and `Fruit` in df 2. You join the data frame by adding the columns from df2 to the right of df1. And you only keep rows where you get a match.

### data using dput()

```
df1 <- structure(list(list_fruit = c("Orange", "Grape", "Watermelon", 
                                     "Mango")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Fruit = c("Banana", "Watermelon", "Pineapple", 
                                "Guava", "Orange"), Number = c(56L, 5L, 96L, 47L, 3L), Price = c(25L, 
                                                                                                 100L, 150L, 20L, 120L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                              -5L))
```